# embed an image in a file

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

MSDN decribes .Net System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon as

> Returns an icon representation of an image that is contained in the specified file,

what I am trying to figure out is how to get the image in the specified file in the first place. The kind of thing I need to do is similar to adding an Internet explorer favourite where each .url internet shortcut has its own different associated icon which can be extracted using ExtractAssociatedIcon. How would I add an image to be used as the file's icon to a file created from c# using FileStream and BinaryFormatter.Serialize. The way the file is created is not set in stone but it needs to contain an instance of a c# class.

Comment: Do you want it to appear in the Shell or only in your app?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an [icon handler shell extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144122%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I remember this from long ago, is it still applicable? [Dont write shell Extensions in .NET](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2005/11/18/494572.aspx)

Comment: @PaulFarry: Not for .Net 4, which supports SxS in-proc